# Aren't these ORMs just ADO.NET with a different name?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I've been reading up on alternatives to Entity Framework, so far I've seen Dapper, OrmLite, NPoco, PetaPoco and Massive.

And they ALL look like ADO.NET with a different name to me. They operate by executing SQL queries, specified in plain text, just like ADO.NET.

I'm sure if you delve *deep* into them there would be *some* difference but am I missing something or are they just *slightly* different from ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Your question starts out talking about Entity Framework, but then it segues into ADO.NET. Those are not the same thing.

Entity Framework is an ORM (object relational mapping) framework, like the other packages you mention in your first paragraph. You're right that they all do essentially the same thing: They let you read and write data from a database by using strongly typed C# objects instead of more abstract concepts like `DataTable` and `DataRow`. The syntaxes are different for each, and you may find some easier to work with than others. You might also be interested in looking at some of the speed benchmarks that are out there for the different frameworks.

It's also important to note that ORMs don't always require you to write plain-text SQL; they take care of generating that themselves. For example, something like this works in PetaPoco and NPoco:

```
public class Holiday
{
    property DateTime Date { get; set; }
    property String Name { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new Database("MyDB"))
{
    // No SQL here -- it gets generated for you
    IEnumerable<Holiday> holidays = db.Query<Holiday>("");
}
```

ADO.NET is the underlying database access technology used by .NET, so anything that talks to a database is going to use that at some point. All of these ORMs rely on ADO.NET.